# split user:pass to user and pass in c#

Tags: c#

So basically I have this program where the user uploads a list of user:pass in that format and I need user to be in it's own string and pass to be in it's own string.

Example of what i tried

```
string Account = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
char[] delimiterChars = { ':' };
Account.Split(delimiterChars);
```

I need to get the front part of user into string user and back part into string pass

Comment: Try google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

Comment: the fact that you can post a sensible question here but cant google how to split a string is absurd

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx I have tried this but i'm not quite sure how to get the front part into string user and the back part into string pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string.split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx):

```
var combined = "user:pass";
var split = combined.Split(new[]{":"});
var user = split[0];
var password = split[1];
```

Comment: My password is `:hard:luck` ... Enjoy ;)